# Android: Getting a message no results found from google maps

Tags: android, eclipse, google-earth, kmz

Iam passing via intent a kml file that i want to open in google maps.

Code:

```
    String uri = "geo:0,0?q=http://195.251.203.174/rapidfire/data/20130628/20130628_179_AQUA_AfternoonPass.kml";
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    startActivity(intent);
```

But when google maps opens it says "no results found". What am i doing wrong?